# Netlify deploy not recognizing AWS s3 holding my images

Tags: html, netlify

I currently deployed my website and attached SRC attributes that point to aws s3 buckets. When I go to look at the website, they won't show up - but I can access the url just fine on the web. I don't know how to fix this. Thank you. Here are how my img tags are set up

```
 <div class="project-card">
        <img
          src="http://baitbots.cdn.s3-website-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/NYT-API-min.png"
          alt="image of New York Times API web application" />
        <p class="project-title">New York Times API</p>
  <div>
```

Comment: link to the website?

Comment: https://infallible-hoover-27b61a.netlify.app/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your app on Netlify use https?

Look for [mixed content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content) warning in your browser console.

You can fix it by setting your CDN to a secure connection https (your image URL).

Comment: You are welcome. If my answer was helpful, please upvote and accept my answer ~